# Video not working in IE 10 without compatibility view enabled

Tags: internet-explorer-10, video.js

i am trying to embed a video on a web page using video.js. 
The video should play on mayor browsers. On Chrome and Firefox it is working fine, but i can not make it work in IE 10 on my local machine (Server 2008 R2). My html code is 100% of the supplied demo.html which is also not working on IE 10. I used absolute urls for video source and added mime types for video formats and additional files in IIS. When i use the compatibility view button, the movie works.

The following error code is displayed in the IE 10 console.

`Video Error,[object Object]`

The video is also working fine when i use another computer (windows 7, with IE 10, and without compatibility view) to surf to my dev machine, so i assume i have a local problem.

How can i debug this?

Comment: why isnt the flash fall back working? what mime types did you specify?

Comment: I have flash installed so i don't know why it isn't working. I will try to investigate this. I added .ogg,.ogv,.mp4 and .woff. The rest (for video.js) was there already. Mime types can not be the problem, because the machine delivers the files and movies correctly to other computers.